# How to distinguish the two different kinds of football from Google results?

Tags: search, search-engine, google-search

If I search soccer, it inevitably excludes most of the non-American sources of the sport because they call it football.

If I search football, resources for American football shows up in large quantities in my result.

My question is, what’s the best way to search for soccer (internationally known as football) resources on the Internet?

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. And @MichaelFrank’s [answer](http://superuser.com/a/886150/167207) is a decent suggestion. But it is something I would seriously consider querying Google directly about. Soccer/football is gaining popularity globally and even in the U.S. so I can imagine you are honing in on something they would need to address at some point if they haven’t already.

Comment: @JakeGould I wonder if Google are actually clever enough to *include* results for football in the results when searching for soccer. If I search for `soccer` here, I get results for the Auckland Football Association. Which doesn't have soccer anywhere on the actual page.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Fair point. Honestly, this is something that should be brought up directly with Google. Past that we’re just coming up with “magic tricks” to solve an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://www.google.co.uk and search for football. I get results only about soccer and not american football.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! There are still a couple American football results get mixed in, but majority of them are now what I expect!

Answer (score 2):

Probably by specifically removing NFL from the search results.

Use `-nfl` as part of your search string.

Comment: This seems to work quite well when searching for news, but less so for more generic searches.

Comment: Honestly, single term search strings are always going to be too broad.